# MySQL error : 1525. Incorrect DATETIME value: ''

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My Query is -

```
SELECT ins.*, ic.* 
FROM insurance_data AS ins 
LEFT JOIN insurance_companies AS ic ON ins.provider = ic.id 
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers AS ph ON (ic.id = ph.foreign_id AND ph.type = 2) 
WHERE (ins.termination_date IS NULL OR ins.termination_date = "" OR 
       ins.termination_date = "0000-00-00") AND ins.provider IS NOT NULL 
 AND ins.provider > 0 
ORDER BY ins.date DESC LIMIT 1
```

I have set SQL Modes in MySQL
to "ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION".
But I am still getting error Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATETIME value: ''.

I am using MySQL ver 8.0.35 on windows 10. I am running query in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Please edit your question and share table definition and the query you have tried

Answer (score 4):

I modified the query to remove the check for an empty string (`''`) in the `termination_date` field, focusing only on `NULL` and valid dates greater than `'0000-00-00'`. Hope this helps to fix the error >>

```
SELECT ins.*, ic.* 
FROM insurance_data AS ins 
LEFT JOIN insurance_companies AS ic ON ins.provider = ic.id 
LEFT JOIN phone_numbers AS ph ON (ic.id = ph.foreign_id AND ph.type = 2) 
WHERE (ins.termination_date IS NULL OR ins.termination_date > '0000-00-00') 
  AND ins.provider IS NOT NULL 
  AND ins.provider > 0 
ORDER BY ins.date DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled strict_trans_mode and enabled ALLOW_INVALID_DATES so empty strings are written to the db as '0000-00-00 00:00:00' but this does not apply to a date check against an empty string

https://dbfiddle.uk/_b6rynV1